# Generating set for sum and product of two ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra

What should be generating sets for sum and product of ideals $<a,b>,<c,d>$, where those ideals are ideals of commutative ring? Can someone explain this to me? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the ring be $R$, then in fact $<a,b>=Ra+Rb$ and $<c,d>=Rc+Rd$, here $Ra=\{r \cdot a| r\in R\}$. So $<a,b>+<c,d>=Ra+Rb+Rc+Rd=<a,b,c,d>$ and $<a,b>\cdot <c,d>=(Ra+Rb)\cdot (Rc+Rd)=Rac+Rad+Rbc+Rbd=<ac,ad,bc,bd>$.